# C++ std::atomic union

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

How do I set a union to be atomic using std::atomic?  Or do I have to declare the members of the union to be atomic instead?

```
typedef union {
    int integer;
    float flt;
    double dbl;
    int *intArray;
    float *floatArray;
    unsigned char *byteArray;
} ValueUnion;

class FooClass {
public:
    std::atomic<ValueUnion> value;

};
```

Access to the union gives an error:

```
foo->value.floatArray = NULL;

error: no member named 'floatArray' in 'std::__1::atomic<ValueUnion>'
                    foo->value.floatArray = NULL;
```

Do I need to do something like:

```
typedef union {
    std::atomic<int> integer;
    std::atomic<float> flt;
    std::atomic<double> dbl;
    std::atomic<int*> *intArray;
    std::atomic<float*> *floatArray;
    std::atomic<unsigned char*> *byteArray;
} ValueUnion;
```

and declare the member variable value to be as below?

```
class FooClass {
public:
    ValueUnion value;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with it.  For example, to store a value into an atomic union:

```
foo->value = []{ ValueUnion u; u.floatArray = NULL; return u; }();
```

or

```
foo->value.store([]{ ValueUnion u; u.floatArray = NULL; return u; }());
```

If you want to be able to perform lock-free atomic arithmetic (e.g. atomic increment) on the contained values then you will need to go for your second design (a union of atomics).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you'll have to use atomic memory access and writes:

```
typedef union {
    int integer;
    float flt;
    double dbl;
    int *intArray;
    float *floatArray;
    unsigned char *byteArray;
} ValueUnion;

class FooClass {
public:
    std::atomic<ValueUnion> value;

}; 
int main()
{
    FooClass obj;
    ValueUnion temp = obj.value.load();
    temp.floatArray = NULL;
    obj.value.store(temp); 
}
```

notice that this doesn't guarantee that the `load/modify/store` sequence is atomic. You'll have to deal with the safety of those instructions yourself (e.g. [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex))